# Выделить домен с помощью регулярного выражения re

Tags: python, регулярные-выражения

У меня есть очень большой файл и мне нужно выделить все доменные имена в каждой строке, но проблема в том что я не могу правильные регекс подобрать, вот как выглядят линки в файле:

```
http://www.test.com/drama/p-s-i-love-you-2007/40321/
http://www.test.com/
http://www.test.com
http://www.test.com//testimonials-2/
http://www.test.com/
http://www.test.com/?q=node/71875
```

А вот мой регекс

```
match = re.search('http://(.+)/*(.*)', line)
```

который не срабатывает во многих случаях. Как мне подобрать универсальный? С питоном и регулярками знаком пока что слабо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется проще вот так сделать, без регулярного выражения:

```
url = "http://www.test.com/drama/p-s-i-love-you-2007/40321/" #1
url = "http://www.test.com" #2
print(url.split("//")[-1].split("/")[0])
#1 www.test.com
#2 www.test.com
```

В итоге получится www.test.com.
Если  включая http://... то есть библиотека

```
import urlparse
url = 'http://www.test.com/drama/p-s-i-love-you-2007/40321/'
urlparse.urljoin(url, '/')
#http://www.test.com/
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, у меня в общем-то такое регекс вышелmatch = re.search('http://(.+?)(/.*)*$', line). Но буду иметь в виду. upd: А что будет если слеша в конце не будет?

Comment: @AlexPetrov, будет www.test.com, без ошибок и варнингов

Answer (score 4):

Для разбора URL более логичным выглядит использование специальных, заточенных под это библиотек, которые уже протестированы и сделают это в максимальном соответствии со спецификациями. Например, urllib, которая входит в стандартную библиотеку Python.

```
urllib.parse.urlsplit("http://www.example.com/...").netloc
```

> 'www.example.com'

Comment: спасибо за библиотеку